# SwiftUI FetchRequest Order Output in Picker

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swiftui

I have a json I am fetching from a remote server that contains a list of countries (and ID, the country name, and the country abbreviation). I am populating a picker with these values via a ForEach.

The two issues I cannot resolve are:

1. I want to display United States as the first choice in the picker, followed by an alphabetical listing of all other countries.

I've thought about using NSPredicate or NSCompoundPredicate but that's just filtering out values. I thought about creating multiple fetchrequests and filtering everything except the US and then the other shows everything but the US. That seemed like a waste, and I wasn't entirely sure how to combine them.

2. Based on the user's selection, I need to populate three variables (id, name, and abbr).

I can bind to the name and it works just fine. Likewise, I can bind the picker to the abbr and it works. However, I cannot figure out how to update all 3 variables as a picker only has a single binding. I tried writing a function that sets all of these variables onTap within the ForEach but that didn't seem like a good plan (or maybe it is?).

Here's some code:

```
@FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: [SortDescriptor(\.name)] var countries: FetchedResults<Picker_Country>

// Load and decode the JSON from remote URL without caching

    func loadCountryData() async {
        
        let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        config.requestCachePolicy = .reloadIgnoringLocalCacheData
        config.urlCache = nil
        let URLSessionNoCache = URLSession(configuration: config)

        guard let url = URL(string: "https://api.foo.com/general/pickers/country_select") else {
            print("Invalid URL")
            return
        }

        do {
            let (data, _) = try await URLSessionNoCache.data(from: url)
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .iso8601
            let countries = try decoder.decode([CountryOptions].self, from: data)
            
            await MainActor.run {
                setCountryArray(with: countries)
            }

        } catch {
            print("Invalid Data")
        }
    }
    
    func setCountryArray(with downloadedCountryOptions: [CountryOptions]) {
        for countries in downloadedCountryOptions {
            let countryPicker = Picker_Country(context: moc)
            
            countryPicker.id =  Int16(countries.id)
            countryPicker.name = countries.name
            countryPicker.abbr = countries.abbr
        }
        try? moc.save()
    }
```

and finally, here is my picker.

(Note: wrappedName and wrappedAbbr and are just vars that allow me to not have to nil coalesce. They correspond directly to name and abbr.)

Obviously by using .tag I am showing the name but only setting the abbr, which is also what the selection is bound to. That's the question of how to set the id, name, and abbr on user selection.

```
Picker("Country", selection: $createUser.countryAbbr) {
    ForEach(countries) { country in
        Text(country.wrappedName).tag(country.wrappedAbbr)
    } // End ForEach
} // End Picker
.pickerStyle(WheelPickerStyle())
.padding()
.labelsHidden()
```

Comment: One alternative to have US at the top is to have it pre-selected by initializing the selection variable with it. Why deconstruct your country object into 3 variables, it will only make it more complicated. Use a single variable holding a country instead and you can also use the whole object as the tag for the picker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was actually a lot simpler than I was making it out to be. When you create a picker without using a ForEach, you do something like:

```
Picker("Fooblah", selection: $fooblah) {
    Text("foo").tag(0)
    Text("blah").tag(1)
} // End Picker
```

Now, because the JSON is being stored in CoreData and we can use NSPredicate to filter the results of a FetchRequest, you perform two FetchRequests as follows:

```
@FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: [], predicate: NSPredicate(format: "abbr == 'US'")) var countryUS: FetchedResults<Picker_Country>
    @FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: [SortDescriptor(\.name)], predicate: NSPredicate(format: "abbr != 'US'")) var countries: FetchedResults<Picker_Country>
```

The first FetchRequest returns only the United States, while the second returns everything EXCEPT for the United States.

Now, when you create your picker you do two ForEach statements, just like you would do two or more Text statements, like this:

```
Picker("Country", selection: $createUser.countryAbbr) {
    ForEach(countryUS) { country in
        Text(country.wrappedName).tag(country.wrappedAbbr)
    } // End US ForEach
    ForEach(countries) { country in
        Text(country.wrappedName).tag(country.wrappedAbbr)
    } // End All except US ForEach
} // End Picker
```

Using CoreData and binding to the abbreviation of the country, you can then create a relationship so that within managedObjectContext you can call to the corresponding country name, just as you can call to the country abbreviation.

Another tip is that if you wish to only use the country abbreviation, but somehow still display the full country name, you can do so via the built-in locale functionality as follows:

```
Text(Locale.current.localizedString(forRegionCode: createUser.countryAbbr) ?? createUser.countryAbbr)
```

Now this is flexible for any type of results you wish to display in a picker from CoreData. Simply modify the NSPredicate filter as appropriate for your situation.

Comment: Note that using two fetch requests are not very effective since there is a performance cost when doing a fetch.

Comment: Seeing as how no one has had any solution to the issue, this is workable code. I agree there is probably a better way to do it, and I am always open to helpful suggestions with real proven code, if you would like to provide some actual assistance instead of just commenting.

Comment: I didn't say this isn't workable but one should be aware of the implications of using this solution so it's more a comment for anyone reading this answer. As for answering, I did offer a way forward in the comments.